# Admin URL is not found in existing Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7

I run *Drupal 7* existing project in `localhost`.

The front end are running successfully but the admin is not working.

Page byu url `localhost/sitename/admin` send the error message `"requested url is not found"`

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

- Check files maybe you have broken files;
- Check your sign in. Do you login? by url `localhost/sitename/user` or drush command `drush uli --uid` ,where uid for superuser is 1 (as it's first user).
- Check your db, maybe it's broken or don't indicated in `settings.php`